# Magento Report Custom Filter without creating custom report module

Tags: php, magento, filter, report, admin

In one of my client's site, Magento-1.9.2.4 CE is installed.

Now I want to add a custom filter menu to `Admin > Reports > Sales` for filtering the Orders in reports by Payment and Shipping method applied during the placing of order(checkout).

Means I want a menu item like `Admin > Reports > Sales > Paymentmethodname(eg. WebPOS)` which gets the Order collection consisting of orders only in which payment is done by `WebPOS` method. Same goes with shipping method filter.

Now I have seen some custom report modules online, but how can I do this by just overriding some block and model files in local codepool ?

Also payment and shipping method columns aren't there in `sales_aggregate...` tables from which reports are fetched.